# Email encryption via TLS

Tags: email, ssl, encryption

When I use TLS for my email delivery, what exactly happens to my data. Is it the data getting encrypted or a secured TLS tunnel is formed and my data goes in that tunnel in plain text ?

Regards
Karthik

Comment: Yes, the data goes into the "tunnel" in unencrypted form, but is encrypted in the middle (at each point beside the two endpoints). What's the issue here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly related to programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. It should be instead asked at security.stackexchange.com.